# Drupal 8: How to edit Paragraph field value?

Tags: php, drupal, module, node-modules, paragraph

i wondering if i can set a value of a paragraph.
in my Module i use a entity_presave function and if i try to get the Paragraph values its working fine but if i try to set or edit a value its not working somehow.

```
function setParagraph($node)
{
  $paragraph = $node->field_paragraphs->getValue();
  // Loop through the result set.
  foreach ($paragraph as $element) {
    $p = \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph::load($element['target_id']);
    $foo = $p->field_foo>value;
    $bar = $p->field_bar->value;

`$foo and $bar are getting filled with the right values`

but if i want to set a value nothing will work 

    $p->set('field_foo', $bar); //not working
    $p->field_foo = $bar;  //not working
    $p->field_foo->value = $bar; notworking
    //$p->set('field_steamconnect', $steamconnect);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph;

$p = Paragraph::Create();
$p->set('field_foo', [
  'field_1' => 'xxx',
  'field_2' => 'yyy',
]); 
$p->save();

$node = Node::Create();
...
$node->set('field_paragraph', [
  'target_id' => $p->id(),
  'target_revision_id' => $p->getRevisionId(),
]);
$node->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

ah

```
$p->set('field_foo', $bar); 
$p->save();
```

will work